# Confused about SLURM: I SSH to a compute node with a private key, so how SLURM is able to access a compute node if I just add a name to slurm.conf?

Tags: ssh, slurm

I'm curious about understanding how slurmctld access to the compute nodes or send info to them. I'm setting up SLURM so is not fully functional yet.

Currently I SSH to the compute node with a private key, i.e, `ssh -i mykey.pem compute-node01`. To set SLURM, I just added the compute node name to slurm.conf (via `slurmd -C`). Then, I copied the munge.key and the slurm.conf to all nodes so they are the same.
Currently, it is not working. I get **munge credential not recognized**. I wonder if it is because everytime I access to a node I must type `ssh -i mykey.pem compute-node0X`, i.e., I must use a private key to access to each node...

I have the following questions:

- how does SLURM get access to the other nodes? I never registered any IP anywhere, I just  added the node name using `slurmd -C` to `slurm.conf`, which according to me, doesn't say anything relevant to have a real connection. Is it because they share the `munge.key` and within this key there is some sort of `ssh -i privatekey IP` connection?
- Is my SSH access with a key blocking SLURM and that's why I get credential not recognized?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slurm does not use SSH to communicate. Once the `munge` daemon and the `slurmd` daemon are up and running, the `slurmd` daemons communicate with the `slurmctld` daemon through Slurm-specific ports provided that

- they share the same munge key
- the server running `slurmd` is registered in the `slurm.conf` of the server running `slurmctld`.
- the firewall does not block communications on slurm port (6818)

The `mykey.pem` SSH key is related to your user account, not to Slurm.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last question may be... Can I have a compute node in Japan and the head node  in Peru? Can slurmd daemons communicate from anywhere with the slurmctld daemon? Or it only works in a local server and why